# Keep non related object in mongodb aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying to make an aggregation on `users` collection and than make a `$lookup` on another collection `usersurveystatuses` to find if this user has completed surveys. This works fine but it projects only users who have matching surveys. How can i keep all the users even if a survey doesn't relate.
Code:

```
db.collection('users')
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: { roles: { $in: ['user'] } },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'usersurveystatuses',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'user_id',
            as: 'completedSurveys',
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$completedSurveys',
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            'completedSurveys.status': 'completed',
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            name: { $first: '$firstname' },
            surname: { $first: '$lastname' },
            credits: { $first: '$credits' },
            completedSurveys: { $push: '$completedSurveys' },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            surname: 1,
            credits: 1,
            completedSurveys: 1,
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray()
      .then(users => {
        console.log(users)
      })
```

Result only returning the user who has completed surveys.

```
[ { _id: 5be98fa0b02eed1b2a17ca54,
    name: 'User',
    surname: 'User',
    credits: 0,
    completedSurveys: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```